# Calculate Key for WebService Update from Sql Query in Navision 2009

Tags: cqrs, dynamics-nav, navision

I am exposing some Pages in Navision 2009 as web services. To update a record, you have to issue a Read request, and send the Key field along with your Update request.

I would rather calculate the Key myself for 2 reasons:

1. Using the filters in the read request is awkward -  a sql query would fit on one line.
2. Performance is terrible.

I've been able to figure out that at least part of the key is a Base64 encoded string of the columns that make up the primary key. I hope that someone can tell me where to look (database, code base, docs, etc) to tell me how the Key is calculated.

Comment: If you dont't _Read_ record how do you know it exists? If you want to modify it then it must be already in database.

Comment: A SQL query, which is orders of magnitude more performant.

Comment: You want to insert with sql query and update with ws-call?

Comment: No. I want to insert / update / delete with the web services and query with SQL. That's why I tagged the post 'CQRS' - The idea is you use one interface optimized for Commands - something that changes state - and another interface optimized for Queries - something that answers a question.

Comment: Maybe the rest of the key is SQL's timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know how to calculate the key. Instead of calculating the key, have you considered doing your data manipulation in a codeunit instead, and exposing that codeunit as a webservice?

Comment: Doesn't make economic sense. We would have to purchase a developer license and then additional code units. Even if I were a C/AL developer, it would take several weeks doing it that way just to break even on cost.

Comment: Ah, I see. You may be right. On the other hand, since the algorithm for  building the key is not documented anywhere, it may be subject to change without any prior notice from Microsoft?